# R heatmap colouring dependant on values being above or below zero

Tags: r, scaling, heatmap

I am trying to make a heatmap in R where my data ranges from -5 to +50. I would like values of 0 to be white, the values between 0 and -5 to be coloured on a gradient from white to blue and the values between 0 and +50 to be coloured from white to red. Ideally, I'd also like the same scaling to be used, i.e. the darkness of blue at -5 to be the same as the darkness of the red at +5.

I have working code for heatmap with the gradient for the whole data set from blue to red with white colouring points close to the mean of the data.

```
hv <- heatmap.2(data_matrix,
    scale="none",
    Rowv=NA, 
    Colv=NA, 
    col = rev(brewer.pal(11,"RdBu")), 
    margins=c(5,5), 
    cexRow=0.5, cexCol=1.0,
    ylab= "Mutations",
    main = "heatmap", 
    key=TRUE,keysize=1.5, trace="none")
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you taken a look at this recent and very similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161014/custom-heat-map-in-r/8161231#8161231

Comment: Do you mean instead that you want "the darkness of blue at -5 to be the same as the darkness of **the red at +50**"? Finally, could you include a small submatrix called `data_matrix` (and calls to `1ibrary(RColorBrewer)` and `library(gplots)`) to make this a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add these to you function.

breaks = c(5/6* -5,5/6* -4,5/6* -3,5/6* -2,5/6* -1,0,5/6* 1,50/6*1,50/6*2,50/6*3,50/6*4,50/6*5)

breaks=breaks

This specifies the breaks you use in the heatmap.
You might try to fudge the numbers a bit, and mayby add a few more colors and breaks, the number of breaks should be number of colors + 1.

Giving this:

```
library(RColorBrewer) 
library(gplots)
data_matrix <- cbind(c(rnorm(30,-2.5,sd= 0.85),rnorm(30,25,sd= 8),rnorm(30,6,sd= 3)),
            c(rnorm(30,-2.5,sd= 0.85),rnorm(30,25,sd= 8),rnorm(30,6,sd= 3)),
            c(rnorm(30,-2.5,sd= 0.85),rnorm(30,25,sd= 8),rnorm(30,6,sd= 3)),
            c(rnorm(30,-2.5,sd= 0.85),rnorm(30,25,sd= 8),rnorm(30,6,sd= 3)))

breaks = c(5/6* -5, 5/6* -4, 5/6* -3, 5/6* -2, 5/6* -1, 0 ,5/6* 1, 50/6*1, 50/6*2, 50/6*3, 50/6*4, 50/6*5)
hv <- heatmap.2(data_matrix, 
    scale="none",
    Rowv=NA,
    Colv=NA,
    col = rev(brewer.pal(11,"RdBu")),
    margins=c(5,5),
    cexRow=0.5, cexCol=1.0, 
    breaks=breaks,
    ylab= "Mutations",
    main = "heatmap",
    key=TRUE,keysize=1.5, trace="none")
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data goes from -5 to +50, having the same gradient for positive and negative values will make the negative colours look pretty much all white,

[image: washedout]

In contrast, the full hue version goes like this,

[image: fullhue]

Comment: How did you create this Baptiste? The lower one is example what I am looking for.

Comment: @Torvon I wrote [some custom grid functions](https://github.com/baptiste/gridplot/blob/master/R/matrixGrob.r), but never got around tidying things up unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please add the code (to add a coloured scale) in your answer?

Comment: I used `colorbarGrob` from the above link