# R heatmap with diverging colour palette

Tags: r, graphics, colors, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to create a simple heatmap in R, using a diverging colour palette. I want to use a gradient so that all numbers below a threshold N are designated a color (say purple), and all numbers above the threshold are designated another color (say orange). The further away the number is from the threshold, the darker the color should be.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
Division,COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7
Division 1,31.9221884012222,75.8181694429368,97.0480443444103,96.295954938978,70.5677134916186,63.0451830103993,93.0396212730557
Division 2,85.7012346852571,29.0621076244861,16.9130333233625,94.6443660184741,19.9103083927184,61.9562198873609,72.3791105207056
Division 3,47.1665125340223,99.4153356179595,8.51091076619923,79.1276383213699,41.915355855599,7.45079894550145,24.6946100145578
Division 4,66.0743870772421,24.6163331903517,78.694460215047,42.04714265652,50.2694897353649,73.0409651994705,87.3745442833751
Division 5,29.6664374880493,35.4036891367286,19.2967326845974,5.48460693098605,32.4517334811389,15.5926876701415,76.0523204226047
Division 6,95.4969164915383,8.63230894319713,61.7535551078618,24.5590241160244,25.5453423131257,56.397921172902,44.4693325087428
Division 7,87.5015622004867,28.7770316936076,56.5095080062747,34.6680747810751,28.1923673115671,65.0204187724739,13.795713102445
Division 8,70.1077231671661,72.4712177179754,38.4903231170028,36.1821102909744,97.0875509083271,17.184783378616,78.2292529474944
Division 9,47.3570406902581,90.2257485780865,65.6037972308695,77.0234781783074,25.6294377148151,84.900529962033,82.5080851092935
Division 10,58.0811711959541,0.493217632174492,58.5604055318981,53.5780876874924,9.12552657537162,20.313960686326,78.1371118500829
Division 11,34.6708688884974,76.711881859228,22.6064443588257,22.1724311355501,5.48891355283558,79.1159523651004,56.8405059166253
Division 12,33.6812808644027,44.1363711375743,70.6362190190703,3.78900407813489,16.6075889021158,9.12654218263924,39.9711143691093
```

Here is a simple snippet to produce a heatmap from the above data

```
data <- read.csv("dataset.csv", sep=",")
row.names(data) <- data$Division
data <- data[,2:7]
data_matrix <- data.matrix(data) 
heatmap(data_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = heat.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
```

How can I modify the above code to produce:

- a color gradient (orange) for all numbers ABOVE 50 (darker the further the number is from 50)
- a color gradient (purple) for all numbers BELOW 50 (darker the further the number is from 50)
- Nice to have (but optional) write the number value in the grid cell
- Nice to have (but optional), use a different color for grid cell that is EXACTLY the threshold number (50 in this case)

**[[Edit]]**

I have just seen this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161014/custom-heat-map-in-r/8161231#8161231), which seems to be very similar. The answer uses ggplot (which I have no experience of), and I have so far, been unable to adapt the ggplot solution to my slightly more complicated data.

Comment: the `RColorBrewer` package has nice palletes: try `RColorBrewer:::brewer.pal(11,"PuOr")`, then specify a breaks argument, though you may need to do that via the `image()` function instead.

Comment: @timriffe -- Nice suggestion. I stole your color scheme for my answer below -- hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien for sure. way to go interpolating over lab space!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should get you most of the way. (Note that you'll need to set `scale="none"` if you want the plotted colors to correspond to the actual (rather than the rescaled) values of the cells).

```
ncol <- 100

## Make a vector with n colors
cols <- RColorBrewer:::brewer.pal(11,"PuOr")  # OR c("purple","white","orange")  
rampcols <- colorRampPalette(colors = cols, space="Lab")(ncol)
rampcols[(n/2) + 1] <- rgb(t(col2rgb("green")), maxColorValue=256) 

## Make a vector with n+1 breaks
rampbreaks <- seq(0, 100, length.out = ncol+1)

## Try it out
heatmap(data_matrix, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale="none",
        col = rampcols, breaks = rampbreaks)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

For finer control over the placement of the threshold, I'd suggest creating two separate palettes -- one for values less than the threshold and one for values above the threshold -- and then "suturing" them together. Try something like this, playing around with different values for `Min`, `Max`, `Thresh`, etc.:

```
nHalf <- 50

Min <- 0
Max <- 100
Thresh <- 50

## Make vector of colors for values below threshold
rc1 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("purple", "white"), space="Lab")(nHalf)    
## Make vector of colors for values above threshold
rc2 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("white", "orange"), space="Lab")(nHalf)
rampcols <- c(rc1, rc2)
## In your example, this line sets the color for values between 49 and 51. 
rampcols[c(nHalf, nHalf+1)] <- rgb(t(col2rgb("green")), maxColorValue=256) 

rb1 <- seq(Min, Thresh, length.out=nHalf+1)
rb2 <- seq(Thresh, Max, length.out=nHalf+1)[-1]
rampbreaks <- c(rb1, rb2)

heatmap(data_matrix, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale="none",
        col = rampcols, breaks = rampbreaks)
```

Comment: Thanks Josh!. I can't believe you managed to create this with such a few number of lines of code!. I am pretty new to all of this (R, RColorBrewer etc), and I am struggling to understand your use of 'magic numbers' (for e.g. `100`, `11` etc), and how it relates to my original data and the 'cutoff threshold value of 50 (as used in my example). Could you please shed some light on: **1.** where the numbers you use are coming from? **2.** How I may set a threshold number?. **3.** It is not clear, how (or where) you are setting the criteria of green background if cell value is approx = threshold.

Comment: @JoshOBrien: Last but not the least, if I wanted to write the values in the cell (like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161014/custom-heat-map-in-r/8161231#8161231), how may I do that?. Thanks

Comment: @JoshOBrien: The reason I was asking about how to set the threshold is so that I could for example, use different colors for positive and negative numbers (by setting the threshold number to 0). I can't work out how to do this from the snippet ...

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli -- There's too much for me to want to explain in there. You should be able to learn how the code works by playing with it, and doing lots of `?xxx` where `xxx = someFunctionMysteriousToMe`.  As for `RColorBrewer`, it's an R interface to the palettes developed by [this project](http://colorbrewer2.org/). Try this to learn a bit more:  `library(RColorBrewer); display.brewer.all(); display.brewer.pal(n=3, "PuOr"); display.brewer.pal(n=7, "PuOr")`, etc... Best of luck! (Note that I've edited my response to give an example of how to more flexibly specify the threshold value.)

Answer (score 4):

I found this thread very useful and also pulled some ideas from [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-November/363655.html), but for my purposes I needed to generalize some things and wanted to use the RColorBrewer package. While I was working on it Dr. Brewer (of Color Brewer fame) stopped in my office and told me I needed to interpolate within the smaller color breaks rather than just pick the end points. I thought others might find this useful so I am posting my function here for posterity.

The function takes in your data vector, the name of a diverging colorBrewer palette, and the center point for your color scheme (default is 0). It outputs a list containing 2 objects: a classIntervals object and a vector of colors: The function is set to interpolate a total of 100 colors but that can be modified with some care.

```
diverge.color <- function(data,pal_choice="RdGy",centeredOn=0){
  nHalf=50
  Min <- min(data,na.rm=TRUE)
  Max <- max(data,na.rm=TRUE)
  Thresh <- centeredOn
  pal<-brewer.pal(n=11,pal_choice)
  rc1<-colorRampPalette(colors=c(pal[1],pal[2]),space="Lab")(10)
  for(i in 2:10){
    tmp<-colorRampPalette(colors=c(pal[i],pal[i+1]),space="Lab")(10)
    rc1<-c(rc1,tmp)
  }
  rb1 <- seq(Min, Thresh, length.out=nHalf+1)
  rb2 <- seq(Thresh, Max, length.out=nHalf+1)[-1]
  rampbreaks <- c(rb1, rb2)
  cuts <- classIntervals(data, style="fixed",fixedBreaks=rampbreaks)
  return(list(cuts,rc1))
}
```

in my work I am using this scheme to plot a raster layer (rs) using spplot like so:

```
brks<-diverge.color(values(rs))
spplot(rs,col.regions=brks[[2]],at=brks[[1]]$brks,colorkey=TRUE))
```