# merging palettes with colorRampPalette and plotting with leaflet

Tags: r, colors, leaflet, maps, color-palette

I'm trying to merge two `colorRampPalette` schemes to use in `leaflet` and have been following this nice  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49126405/how-to-set-up-asymmetrical-color-gradient-for-a-numerical-variable-in-leaflet-in). That example works fine but I can't seem to get it to work for my work, reproducible example below. I'm using `RdYlGn` palette and I want numbers below the threshold to be dark green and numbers above the threshold to more red (skipping some of the inner colors).

For my example my cut-off is `nc$PERIMETER` < 1.3 so I want numbers under this value to be green and everything above more red (color `#FDAE61` onwards).

```
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

#palette im using
palette <- rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdYlGn"))
# [1] "#006837" "#1A9850" "#66BD63" "#A6D96A" "#D9EF8B" "#FFFFBF" "#FEE08B" "#FDAE61" "#F46D43" "#D73027" "#A50026"
previewColors(colorNumeric(palette = palette, domain = 0:10), values = 0:10)


# preparing the shapefile
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON')
nc

x <- sum(nc$PERIMETER < 1.3)  
x # number of values below threshold = 21


### Create an asymmetric color range
## Make vector of colors for values smaller than 1.3 (21 colors)
rc1 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#006837", "#1A9850"), space = "Lab")(x)    #21 

## Make vector of colors for values larger than 1.3 
rc2 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#FDAE61", "#A50026"), space = "Lab")(length(nc$PERIMETER) - x)

## Combine the two color palettes
rampcols <- c(rc1, rc2)

mypal <- colorNumeric(palette = rampcols, domain = nc$PERIMETER)
previewColors(colorNumeric(palette = rampcols, domain = NULL), values = 1:length(nc$PERIMETER))
```

looking at the preview it seems to have worked (21 values under 1.3 should be green):

[image]

plotting it:

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = nc,
              fillOpacity = 0.7,
              fillColor = ~mypal(PERIMETER),
              popup = paste("PERIMETER: ", nc$PERIMETER) )
```

plots ok but doesn't give the right color, the one highlighted is above the threshold (1.3) and so shouldn't be green but it is:

[image]

I thought the way I was creating the palettes was wrong but the preview seems to suggest I've done it right?

anyone have any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I somewhat feel responsible for this question since I wrote that answer. I cannot tell how leaflet is assigning colors to polygons. But I think we witnessed that your approach is not working. Based on my previous idea, I did the following for you. I created a new continuous variable (i.e., `ranking`). This information is the order of values in `PERIMETER`.  In this way, the minimum value of `PERIMETER` (i.e., 0.999) is getting the first color for sure. In my previous answer here, I suggested using `colorFactor()`, but that gave you a hard time to create a legend. So here is additional information. When I created a legend, I used `ranking` in `colorNumeric()` and created a palette, which is `mypal2`. We are using identical information to fill in polygons and add a legend, but we use different functions (either colorFactor or colorNumeric). Once we have the legend, we gotta change the label format. Hence we use `labelFormat()`. I am using `ranking` as indices and getting values in `PERIMETER`.

```
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

#palette im using
palette <- rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdYlGn"))
# [1] "#006837" "#1A9850" "#66BD63" "#A6D96A" "#D9EF8B" "#FFFFBF" "#FEE08B" "#FDAE61" "#F46D43" "#D73027" "#A50026"
previewColors(colorNumeric(palette = palette, domain = 0:10), values = 0:10)


# preparing the shapefile
nc2 <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
       st_transform(st_crs(4326))


# Add sequence information in order to create 108 categories for
# colorFactor(). I sorted the data and added the sequence information.

arrange(nc2, PERIMETER) %>% 
mutate(ranking = 1:n()) -> nc2

x <- sum(nc2$PERIMETER < 1.3)   
x # number of values below threshold = 21


### Create an asymmetric color range
## Make vector of colors for values smaller than 1.3 (21 colors)
rc1 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#006837", "#1A9850"), space = "Lab")(x)    #21 

## Make vector of colors for values larger than 1.3 
rc2 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#FDAE61", "#A50026"), space = "Lab")(length(nc2$PERIMETER) - x)

## Combine the two color palettes
rampcols <- c(rc1, rc2)

# Create a palette to fill in the polygons
mypal <- colorFactor(palette = rampcols, domain = factor(nc2$ranking))
previewColors(colorNumeric(palette = rampcols, domain = NULL), values = 1:length(nc$PERIMETER))


# Create a palette for a legend with ranking again. But this time with
# colorNumeric()

mypal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = rampcols, domain = nc2$ranking)

leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>%
addPolygons(data = nc2,
            fillOpacity = 0.7,
            fillColor = ~mypal(nc2$ranking),
            popup = paste("PERIMETER: ", nc2$PERIMETER)) %>% 
addLegend(position = "bottomright", pal = mypal2, values = nc2$ranking,
          title = "PERIMETER",
          opacity = 0.7,
          labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) nc2$PERIMETER[x]))
```

[image]

If I set up the threshold level at 2.3 (less than 2.3), I get this.

[image]

Comment: I am off to bed. If you need further help, please wait till tomorrow.

Comment: excellent, thank you, so what is my approach mapping exactly? Does it jump to the nearest integer or something? You could plot my way and not realise it was wrong!

Comment: another follow up q, if we add `%>% 
  addLegend( pal = mypal, values = nc$category)` the legend now understandably has 108 categories. I could manually take samples from `mypal(nc$category)` and add them as `colors =c("#EF9656"...` and get their associated `nc$PERIMETER` values but I feel theres a short way to do this if we could do something along the lines of switching `nc$category` back to continuous? Would you have any suggestions for this? thanks

Comment: @user63230 I will take time once my work is done today.

Comment: @user63230 I just came home and revising this idea. I will post my update soon.

Comment: @user63230 I just posted my revision. I hope this is enough for you.

Comment: hmm, this is definitely the kind of thing I had in mind (thank you) but I don't think its working the way we think it is, if we change the cut-off to `x <- sum(nc$PERIMETER < 2.5)` and rerun - almost all legend is green, when we just want below 2.5 green?

Comment: @user63230 Did you regenerate color palettes?

Comment: yes, also when you rerun with the new cut-off (<2.5), the polygon at `PERIMETER` = 2.365 is not green when it should be, not sure whats happening.

Comment: @user63230 I think I fixed the issue. Let me post what I got for now. After this I need to go to bed. Hope you understand that.

Comment: @user63230 I receive `Warning message:In st_cast.sf(., "POLYGON") :
  repeating attributes for all sub-geometries for which they may not be constant`. When we rerun codes, we may be messing around `nc`. This is something we want to be aware of.

Comment: @user63230 On my side, when I change the values (1.3, and 2.5), I think I am getting the right outputs now. That is all I can say for now. I will come back here tomorrow and see what is happening on your side.

Comment: thanks for all your help. Your new plot above is showing the wrong legend though, the criteria is anything below 2.5 is green but the legend says anything under ~ 3.1, thats the issue I'm coming across too

Comment: @user63230 I am about to go to bed. One last thing for tonight is that, if you can, you want to create a legend with colorfactor and try to change labels. Or you try to create a legend with colornumeric by twisting the number of colors you creates. That is all I can imagine in a minute now.

Comment: @user63230 If we keep things positive, at least fill colors are working. I will take some time tomorrow and see what I can do for the legend. Meanwhile please try some ideas by yourself. Hope we work together and find a solution.

Comment: i think the problem is `mypal2`, `plot(rep(1, 108), col = mypal(nc$ranking), pch = 19, cex = 3)` and `plot(rep(1, 108), col = mypal2(nc$PERIMETER), pch = 19, cex = 3)` are different when they should be the same. i think you need to create a `rc3`, `rc4` for a separate `rampcols` to use in `mypal2`. The problem then is I dont know what value to use for `x` because its no longer `x <- sum(nc$PERIMETER < 2.5)`. The answer seems to be a number representing a proportion along `diff(range(nc$PERIMETER))`....this seems hacky but maybe a possible way to do it? but would prefer a repeatable approach..

Comment: @user63230 I think the most straightforward and clean way would be to use the same palette in both. If we can find a way to change labels in the legend from 1-100 to actual numbers in `PERIMETER`, I think we could solve this issue. I will study `labelFormat` in `addLenend()` today.

Comment: @user63230 I got an idea. Let me play around a bit.

Comment: @user63230 I will edit my text a bit later since I got things to do. But I hope you can try the code.

Comment: @user63230 I think this is the best I can do. If you need more complicated things, I think you want to create another question. There are some SO users who can control leaflet better than me.

Comment: this is so helpful, thank you very much. I'll be interested to see how it works on my own data on monday. As a matter of interest when you say "I am using `ranking` as indices", what are the indices or how are they chosen? If we remove duplicate `PERIMETER`s (`nc2 <- nc2 %>% 
  group_by(PERIMETER) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1)`), we get a much more evenly distributed legend!

Comment: @user63230 I do not fully understand the source code, but addLegend is creating break points. We used 1-100. If the first value is chosen for the break, `PERIMETER[1]` is the first value. So I tried to extract values that are used for the breaks using `ranking` as indices in square brackets. I hope I am making sense to you. I proposed this idea in the linked question. Now I think I can say this is the completion of the proposal. This was pretty intense. But I am glad that things are working now.

Comment: for anyone looking for the equivalent of this using `ggplot`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327158/merging-palette-colors-colorramppalette-and-plotting-with-ggplot/