# merging palette colors colorRampPalette and plotting with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, leaflet, maps

I'm trying to replicate using `ggplot2`, an earlier question i had using [leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321495/merging-palettes-with-colorramppalette-and-plotting-with-leaflet/). I'm trying to merge two palettes where one is used if my variable is below a certain threshold and another if above a certain threshold. As I did with my `leaflet` question my final plot doesn't seem to be correct. I also want to convert the factor legend to a continuous one. Example code:

```
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

# preparing the shapefile
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON')

# Create 108 categories

mutate(nc, category = ntile(PERIMETER, n = 108)) -> nc

x <- sum(nc$PERIMETER < 1.3)  
x # number of values below threshold = 21


### Create an asymmetric color range
## Make vector of colors for values smaller than 1.3 (21 colors)
rc1 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#006837", "#1A9850"), space = "Lab")(x)    #21

## Make vector of colors for values larger than 1.3
rc2 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#FDAE61", "#A50026"), space = "Lab")(length(nc$PERIMETER) - x)

## Combine the two color palettes
rampcols <- c(rc1, rc2)

mypal <- colorFactor(palette = rampcols, domain = nc$category)
previewColors(colorNumeric(palette = rampcols, domain = NULL), values = 1:length(nc$PERIMETER))


nc %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = factor(category))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mypal(nc$category), guide = FALSE)
```

gives this plot:

[image]

but the leaflet plot (correct coloring)

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = nc,
              fillOpacity = 0.7,
              fillColor = ~mypal(nc$category),
              popup = paste("PERIMETER: ", nc$PERIMETER)) %>%
  addLegend( pal = mypal, values = nc$category)
```

gives this correct plot:

[image]

You can see the `ggplot` figure is not the same which I can't fix.

Additionally when I add a legend to the `ggplot`, I get a factor legend for the new palette but I want a continuous one (even if the variable is a factor):

```
nc %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = factor(category))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mypal(nc$category))
```

[image]

Would anyone know how to fix the coloring issue and alter the associated legend in continuous form? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think is caused by the use of `factor()`, using the following code:

```
nc %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = factor(category))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mypal(levels(factor(nc$category))), guide = FALSE)
```

gives you a map with the same coloring as leaflet does.

[image: result]

Comment: thanks, that sorted the colors! would you know how to incorporate a continuous legend but keep the `scale_fill_manual`?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this, the closest answer I could find was to use `scales` package following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299705/asymmetric-color-distribution-in-scale-gradient2) instead of `scale_fill_manual`. Using this approach, I no longer use `mypal` but enter the colours manually at the cut point with the trick of putting in `1.299` instead of `1.3` (`rescale(c(.999, 1.2999, 1.3, 3.640))` instead of `rescale(c(.999, 1.2999, 1.3, 3.640))`)

```
library("scales")
range(nc$PERIMETER)
#[1] 0.999 3.640
nc %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = PERIMETER)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("#006837", "#1A9850", "#FDAE61", "#A50026"), 
                       values = rescale(c(.999, 1.2999, 1.3, 3.640))
                       #guide = "colorbar"
                       #limits=c(-.1,.3)
  )
```

giving:

[image]